# Windows version of x2g client flagged as malware when downloading from x2g.org

Tags: client, malware, x2go

When downloading the x2go client for Windows from x2go.org, Firefox as well as Edge claim that it's malware. Virustotal does not flag it. I would assume this to be a common issue but the FAQ from x2go does not mention it and searching the web also does not really result in any usefull hints. Can anyone here sheed some light on this?
TIA

download and install the x2go client for Windows to no avail